# nouns followed by infinitives

Tags: infinitive-clauses

I have sometimes problem understanding these structures. I just came across this expression:

> **Materials to make sarin gas and perhaps other toxic chemicals** moved freely cross-border from Turkey to Syria.

"**Materials to make sarin gas and perhaps other toxic chemicals** ."              Here we can sense that materials are not the subject which will make sarin and other chemicals by itself.In this context , we can infer that the infinitive clause is used in a way that the meaning is close to "materials which is necessary to make sarin gas and other chemicals".

I will give another example and hence my confusion will be revealed.

> The woman to save you
>   The institution to supervise the process

In these examples , we can safely infer that the subject is nouns which are both followed by infinitive clause. The woman is subject. The institution is subject.

So why there is difference? Am i missing a point? In the very first example I gave , the subject is not clear as it is understood from the context.We don't know the subject.
Genereally , in the pattern of noun+to+verb+object i want to be enlightened as to subject-object relations of this pattern.

Comment: To put it very briefly, why do you think "materials" is not the subject of the sentence?

Comment: @stangdon Do you think "materials" have got an ability to make sarin gas and other whatever chemicals?

Comment: In English, it is perfectly normal for inanimate things to be the subject of a verb phrase, and "X and Y make Z" is a normal phrasing.

Answer (score 1):

In your original sentence, "Materials to make sarin gas and perhaps other toxic chemicals moved freely cross-border from Turkey to Syria", yes, "materials" is the subject of the sentence.  If you look carefully at the sentence, you will see that at its heart it is a simple subject-verb sentence:  *Materials moved.*  Everything else in the sentence is explanatory:  
**Materials** 
*what kind?* to make sarin gas and perhaps other toxic chemicals
**moved**
*how did they move?* freely cross-border from Turkey to Syria.

Your understanding of the bolded part of the sentence is basically correct, though.  The construction **noun verb-infinitive**, like *materials to make sarin gas* or *the woman to save you* or *the organization to supervise the process*  means essentially **noun for the purpose of verb-ing**.  The materials *for the purpose of making sarin gas* moved freely; the woman *for the purpose of saving you* did whatever; the organization *for the purpose of supervising the process* did whatever.

Comment: Well , the sentence is an  excerpt from a facebook page and this sentence was used as headline.Since passive form is mostly ignored in headlines, we can assume that the sentence is passive voice.My point, "materials " are devoid of an ability to create or make gases or whatsoever.Materials can not itself make or produce something.But in the other examples , the action stated by verbs are to be realized by nouns.We can infer that." A women to save you.." Women is to realize the action which is saving. But materials can not realize the action following "materials". Herein lies my confusion .

Comment: I agree that in headlines a lot of the ordinary rules get thrown out, so yes, it could be short for "materials *were* moved".  However, "materials" is still the subject of the sentence, even if the sentence is passive.

Answer (score 0):

> Ingredients to make a birthday cake, and what looked like party hats,
>   were in the shopping basket.

It's not clear whether all of the ingredients required to make a cake were in the basket (maybe sugar was missing, for example, or baking powder), but the ingredients in the basket could be described as those that go into making a cake.

The clause "and what looked like party hats" is simply additional information, unrelated to the *ingredients*.